# What is the "group name" for students who entered / left university in the same year?

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

For example, I entered my university in 2006, so I am a student of "grade 2006" (a direct translation from my own language). What is the proper English?

Besides, I need the word for students graduated in the same year, for me, 2010.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "Class of 2004" and "Batch of 2004"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/what-is-the-difference-between-class-of-2004-and-batch-of-2004)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In English, or at least in the US, we normally group students by the year of graduation rather than the year of entrance. We would say you're part of the "Class of 2010." If we need to group by year of entrance, we would probably say you're part of the "Freshman Class of 2006."

Comment: Often abbreviated to "schoolname 'two-digit year", as in `Yale '06`

Comment: To clarify, one would ask the question 'What year are you?' (never 'what class are you?') with answer 'class of oh-six' or class of twenty-twelve'. Also, one only uses the number of the expected year of graduation so that 'Freshman, class of 2015' means that you're a freshman now in 2011 but will graduate in 2015 (the usual course of things for a 4-year college program).

Comment: In English universities it's more common to use matriculation year rather than graduation year. So Class of 2014 would be matriculating in 2014, and graduating in 2017.

Answer (score 10):

The word used for this within educational circles, in Britain at least, is [**cohort**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohort_%28educational_group%29).

A cohort of students usually means a group of students in the same year on the same course, but could also be extended to wider groups such as all the students studying a course regardless of year, or all students in a single year group.

Comment: I was thinking of cohort too, since it's used for sociology

Comment: I have also heard this in the US.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you are an [alumnus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alumnus) (to mean an "Old student"). The plural form is [alumni](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alumni) (to mean "old students").

Unlike the usage "Class of 2010", the words *Alumni/Alumnus* simply mean *old students of/old student of*, without making any reference to the year of graduation. 
So, *Alumni* is open-ended. It refers to *all the students who have graduated from the institution since its inception*. You will have to specify it on the timeline by saying 'alumni from the year XXXX', or 'alumnus from the year XXXX' to refer to a particular batch or person from the institution's historical records.

If you graduated from an all-women's college, then the feminine equivalents [alumna / alumnae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alumnus) may be used.

In commonwealth countries, the term [batchmate](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&noj=1&biw=1024&bih=581&q=batchmate%20meaning&btnG=Search) is informally/semi-formally used to refer to your alumnus.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Besides previously-mentioned batch, class, and cohort, the phrases "intake students" and "intake of students" are in use, the latter more commonly according to [ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=intake+students%2Cintake+of+students&year_start=1930&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, I would call them your *classmates*.