# What are entries of the same year called

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I want to know a word for a group of students who enroll in a university at the same department at the same time. I tried looking it up in google but didn't get any real results.

Comment: One could say that they are in _the same cohort_, perhaps.

Comment: They're in the same *class* (or, sometimes in sociological or marketing contexts, the same *cohort*).

Comment: So I should say for example : cohort of 2010? or cohort of students of 2010? (when I want to say students who entered in 2010)

Comment: @soroosh.strife I'd just say Class of 2010. That's how I've always known it, at least in the American school system.

Comment: @soroosh.strife: I wouldn't advise ***cohort*** in such contexts because of the negative connotations. Note [definition 3 here:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cohort) *3 often **DEROGATORY** - a supporter or companion*. I'd stick with something more neutral, such as *"the 2010 **intake**"*

Comment: @Fumble *Cohort* is **exactly** what is used in this context in the UK.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: So it would seem - [particularly in the last couple of decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cohort+of+students&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccohort%20of%20students%3B%2Cc0). I suspect this modern usage owes more to the field of sociological statistics than academic year-groups in general. Maybe it's just my age showing, but the first thing it calls to mind for me is [definition #5 here](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cohort) *- an accomplice; abettor*. I don't say it's not used, but I wouldn't advise it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be thinking of *batch* or *cohort*.

> The **batch** of students that enrolled this year are very naughty.
>
> The **cohort** of students that graduated last year have all found jobs.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to say the "the ____ of 2010", the word you're looking for is ***class***:

> a body of students or alumni whose year of graduation is the same

[Merriam-Webster online, entry for class, n.](http://i.word.com/idictionary/class)

Comment: Which year does "2010" refer to? The year they entered, or the year they left?

Comment: The year they left. If you join as a junior in 2008, then you're still in the *class of 2010* (because it is expected you will graduate 2 years hence, along with our classmates who enrolled as freshmen in 2006).

Comment: So as an answer to the expanded question in the comments, "I want to say students who entered in 2010," this isn't particularly good, or at least, it's not clear.

Comment: I didn't see that expansion. Thanks for pointing  out the update.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on whether you're talking about undergraduate or graduate? e.g. if you're a PhD coming in 2010, doesn't that make you class of 2010 rather than (say) class of 2016, since it's hard to predict when you'd be graduating?

Answer (score 2):

I would call them 'The 2010 intake'. That is the way in which schoolchildren are described in Britain and I see no reason not to use it for university students.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question (in the comments) of what to call students who entered in 2010, you can just call them "2010 enrollees".

Answer (score 0):

"Matriculant".

A person who has matriculated or been registered on a list or roll, usually at a school.
See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matriculant

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far have given the same set of words listed in similar questions [What is the difference between “Class of 2004” and “Batch of 2004”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/7928) and [What is the “group name” for students who entered / left university in the same year?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/41673). (*[Matriculant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matriculant)*, not mentioned in either question, perhaps is an exception, although *matriculating* and *matriculation* appear in comments to them.)

Note that none of the terms proffered so far address the “at the same department” provision of the present question.  Constructions like *English department cohort* or *Math department cohort* would do so, at the cost of more words.  Informally, one might refer to such a group as a  *[coterie](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coterie#Noun)* (“An exclusive group of people, who associate closely for a common purpose; a clique”) or  *[clique](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/clique#Noun)* (“A small, exclusive group of individuals; [cabal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cabal#Noun)”).  In some cases, the departmental faculty and graduate advisors may be a *[camarilla](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/camarilla#Noun)*.

[Link sources: ELU and Wiktionary]