# What is an "in honors" school student in the US?

Tags: transatlantic-differences

I came across this sentence on an American website

> Aron is a student in honors in his class

I was wondering how to phrase this for a UK audience.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by an "in honors" school student.

Comment: In secondary education (high school) Honors are specially-designated advanced courses. Also known as Advanced Placement. In post-secondary (college / university), it’s a particular GPA level, with the common Summa or Magna Cum Laude (the latter being unique for a given cohort).  The equivalent in the UK is a scholastic and academic questions, nor an English one. But for resume purposes you’d have to determine if you (or whoever) were invited into, enrolled, and passed the specially-designated courses or achieved the required GPA. Researching that will give you the appropriate title, too.

Comment: In college it's often worded "with honors", and is regarded as equivalent to "cum laude".

Comment: Can you give a link to the original? As an AmE speaker, it sounds really strange to me. I'd say more naturally "Aron is an honors student in his class"

Comment: You can't because the system is different. You would have to explain it or gloss it.

Comment: The "in" honors confuses me.  A kid who gets consistently high grades qualifies for "honors" society, and is frequently an "honors" student.  But - 'in an honors class' , or "taking honors classes"  means taking an advanced level of a subject for a grade level.  Very often an 'honors course' give a student an extra point .. normally an 'A' is 4 points, 'B' grade is 3 points, C 2 points. Often for honors coursed an 'A' counts as 5 points, B as 4 etc. We also have a type of honors courses called AP courses with that higher weight chance to a test to get college credit from the high school course

Answer (score 2):

More context is needed before we can say definitively what meaning is intended, as *honors* and *in honors* are ambiguous (as, indeed, is *[class](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68325/)*), but as Dan Bron notes in a comment, this is likely a reference to *[tracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracking_%28education%29)* in American education. I do not think an exact equivalent exists in the UK.

Being *in honors in my class* would be ellipsis for being either

- enrolled in the *honors* version of a course, i.e. a more rigorous or more advanced version of a general course: *honors chemistry*, *honors French*, *honors algebra*, etc.
- enrolled in the *honors track*, i.e. taking a course load primarily of classes designated as honors classes.

The Merriam-Webster definition of *[honor](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honors)* includes

> 6e. **honors** *plural* (2) : a course of study for superior students supplementing or replacing a regular course

and similarly the American Heritage Dictionary [offers](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=honors)

> 4. **honors**
>      c. A program of advanced study for exceptional students:
>
>    > planned to take honors in history.

@lbf suggests *in honors* refers to being an *honor student* or being a member of an *honor society* or graduating *with honors*. Frequently that may be the case, but not always. A student in the standard track could receive scholastic recognitions. Likewise, a student in the honors track could perform poorly and receive no honors.

---

Students in most traditional U.S. schools, public and private, are assessed based on standardized testing, scholastic performance, and other measures, then placed into *tracks*. Instead of enrolling at a separate *gymnasium*, *lyceum*, or *grammar school* as historically done in various parts of Europe, high-achieving students will attend the same school as others, but take separate classes featuring a more rigorous curriculum.

Both the theory and practice of tracking have [been controversial](https://www.theatlantic.com/education/archive/2014/11/modern-day-segregation-in-public-schools/382846/), but this system has been the norm in mainstream American education since the early- to mid-20th century.

The more advanced classes are frequently called *honors* classes, although they may also be known as *college prep* or *advanced* or many other names. The specifics of what the label entails vary more considerably, and schools may have any number of tracks. In some cases, *honors* overlaps with other intensified curricula such as the International Baccalaureate, the Advanced Placement program, the New York Regents Diploma, and so on, while in other cases it is distinct from them, and either the more or the less rigorous course.

In informal conversation, being *in* can refer either to enrollment in the *honors* version of an individual course, or in the overall track identified as *honors*, a usage likewise extended any reference to a track:

> Did you finish the *Oedipus Rex* reading yet?
>   No; I'm in honors, and we're doing *Philoctetes* instead.
>
> Are you taking AP Physics next year?
>   I can't; it's only offered during second period, and I have to take TOK then, because I'm in IB.

This is largely a colloquial and conversational usage. More formally, one would write out *I'm in the honors class* or *I'm in the honors track* to specify.

Comment: This is the sentence as I came across it, it is part of a mathematical equation in our internal website so I can't really share the link : "The probability that a student is in honors, given that he or she is in Mrs. Christopher’ class, is ...". Thank you so much for your answers everyone!

Answer (score 0):

What is an “in honors” school student in the US?

An **honor** student in the U.S. typically is a student recognized for achieving high academic grades or high marks in their coursework at school.

Here are 2 links describing high school and college honor designations.

[wikipedia - Honors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honors_student)
[wikipedia - Latin Honors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_honors)

Collegiate honors frequently use the Latin designations. Some 'grade' schools (pre-K to ~ 8th grades) use various 'honors' also. Without seeing  'in honors' at said site, I does sound off.  Aaron is an honor student etc ... sounds better.

Comment: A student who wins awards or gets admitted to an honor society wouldn't describe him- or herself as being *in honors*, however, unless speaking in a *very* affected manner. On the other hand, being *in honors* to refer to an honors class or honors program is very common.